# Чем бэкенд сайта отличается от CRM?

Tags: php, laravel, crm, project

Есть бэкенд сайта, на котором можно сгенерировать отчет зарплат сотрудников, там используется api redmine.

Собственно задача такова, что необходимо перенести эту генерацию в CRM.

Тогда вопрос, а в чем будет различие одного от другого?

Сами проекты на Laravel

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: тем что первый был написан на фреймворке, а другой - плагином к crm

Comment: Спасибо. Но все равно не совсем понятно. Можно ли более подробно, потому что изначально была задача развернуть проект на Laravel. И якобы это должно быть CRM

Comment: Насколько я знаю, плагины для Redmine разрабатываются на Ruby, ссылка на [документацию](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/plugin_tutorial).

Comment: "Бекенд" и "CRM" написаны на Laravel?

Comment: @YauhenKib Да, Laravel

Comment: В качестве CRM используется Redmine, разве нет?

Comment: @Simon Видимо, так и есть

Comment: Redmine написан на Rudy.